# Is this sentence a run-on?

Tags: lists, neither-nor, run-on-sentence

However, the courts in Lundy held that because the landlords never seen the dog, nor received complaints about the dog, nor visited the property, nor knew the size or age of the dog, that the landlords were not aware of the dangerous propensities of the dog.

Comment: It should be *landlords **had** never seen*. It would also be more natural if you left out all of the *nor*s, and replaced the final *nor knew* with *or* ***known***. Last, the final comma after *dog* should be removed. It's not a run-on sentence as much as it is unnaturally phrased. It would also sound better to replace the final *the dog* with a pronoun.

Comment: In other words: *However, the courts in Lundy held that because the landlords **had** never seen the dog, received complaints about the dog, visited the property, **or known** the size or age of the dog that the landlords were not aware of **its** dangerous propensities.*

Comment: Ok thank you very much!

Comment: If you're asking what a run-on sentence *is*, you can look at [Is this DFW line a run on sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/66063/291924) and [Can you tell me what are “run-on sentences” exactly and why some people claim this blog post is unreadable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/117327/291924). It's not entirely clear if you were just looking for writing advice, or to understand the definition of the term. (But this question either becomes off topic or a duplicate of one of those.)

Comment: The word 'that' is better deleted: "because ... the age of the **dog, the landlords** were not aware."

Comment: Actually, I would additionally move the last part of the sentence at the beginning, so as to make it easier to parse: *However, the courts in Lundy held that the landlords were not aware of the dangerous propensities of the dog because **they** had never seen **it**, received complaints about **it**, visited **its** property, or known **its** size or age.*

Comment: @YosefBaskin No, in that exact construction, the additional *that* should remain. Without it, the sense of the overall sentence is lost. It's needed because of the intervening text between the first part of the sentence and the last. However, my last comment that reconstructs the sentence removes that problem.